# Recaptcha v2 генерация токена на своём сайте для теста

Tags: php, recaptcha

Хочу на своём сайте тестировать проверку токена (ответа на капчу) в коде php. 
 Есть возможность его получить не решая капчу лично, если эта капча с моего сайта, может кто в теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем виде нельзя.
Но есть тестовая пара ключей, которая позволить протестировать работоспособность капчи не вываливая Вам усложненные варианты в духе "выберите все изображения с дорожными знаками", и на все запросы будет приходить что ответ валиден.

```
Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe
```

Подробнее тут - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.